# EmojiCompat generated id 'android:id/inputExtractEditText'

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I want to add EmojiCompat to my app. However, the project cannot be built due to a warning :

> Error:(23) warn: generated id 'android:id/inputExtractEditText' for external package 'android'.

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmAuc.png)

This layout XML *input_method_extract_view.xml* is provided by the appcompat library and I have tried in the EmojiCompat demo project which can build successfully.

- build tool version 26.0.1
- appcompat version 26.0.1
- Kotlin version 1.1.4-3

I have tried to build with the default one in Android Studio and JRebel for Android, both of them build failed.

Answer (score 1):

if possible ignore the error. the issue will be fixed in the next support library release (28).

Answer (score 1):

You might get that warning when building your app, if your XML layout contains an item with an `id` like this:

```
android:id="@+android:id/title"
```

or

```
android:id="@+android:id/summary"
```

The fix is to either remove the "+", and use an existing `id` in the "android" namespace:

```
android:id="@android:id/title"
```

Or remove the `"android:"` part, to avoid using the "android" namespace at all:

```
android:id="@+id/title"
```

More info and examples:

- https://review.lineageos.org/c/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_PackageInstaller/+/242682  (click on the XML files to see the changes)
- [Is there any legitimate use for @+android:id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591176/is-there-any-legitimate-use-for-androidid)